# difference between CRUD in the front-end Angular and CRUD in the back end

Tags: angular, frontend, backend

I want to ask about the difference between the front-end CRUD and Back-end CRUD operations using JavaScript Frameworks. (Specially Angular)! when i create a web project.

Comment: ok, what about it do you have questions on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not just an Angular question but a general programming question. I'll try to answer it roughly in a way that'll make sense.

When working on an application usually the information is being stored at a database, and you use a backend to communicate with the database, add or update information there etc.

In order to do that, you need to communicate from your front end to your backend, this is what you might define as the 'front-end crud'.

Pretty much what it means is having functions that call the Http request to preform the CRUD actions. More specifically in Angular's case, having a service and CRUD functions inside that service that are responsible for calling the backend.

One more caveat - usually just calling the Http request with the data is not enough, and you want to handle the data that's being stored in your state too. For example - if you have an app that has a user and you want to update the user name, you'd want to do it in the database but also in your app state, otherwise the change won't be shown in the user's screen until they refresh.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome :)